# Python subprocess.Popen() with Pygame , how to tell Pygame wait untill subprocess is done

Tags: python, pygame, subprocess, python-3.4

I have a major issue that too many Pygame users has, I want to take input from user in Pygame. I probably check all informations in internet,include stackoverflow, nothing solved.

So I decide to make a solution, I created another Python script(I convert it to .exe so subprocess can open it) that asking question to user before Pygame is running, after then that script saving user's data into a .txt file(like a database).Then in Pygame I opening that .txt file and taking the data. Therocially it's working, but problem is, I have to tell Pygame, while subprocess is processing, wait for it. That's how I can dodge errors like IndexError etc. Because I'm using *readlines()* and untill that .exe file is closed, Pygame has to wait, if not; *readlines()* giving data as *list* and it throwing IndexError normally. So Pygame has to wait untill I put the data in that .exe file. Let me explain with my codes;

This is the script that taking data from user(I converted it to exe already so subprocess can open):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*-coding:utf-8-*-

while True:
    user=input("Please enter your name: ")
    try:
        user_age=int(input("Please enter your age: "))
    except ValueError:
        print ("Invalid characters for 'age', try again.")
        continue
    ask_conf=input("Are you confirm these informations?(Y/N): ")
    if ask_conf.lower()=="y":
        with open("informations.txt","w") as f: #create the file
            f.write(user+"\n")
            f.write(str(user_age))
        break
    else:
        continue
```

And then, in Pygame, I'am opening this .exe file, but Pygame won't wait and normally I'm getting error.

```
pygame.init()
subprocess.Popen(["wtf.exe"]) #the exe file that taking data from user 
                              #and saving it in "informations.txt"
#codes..
....
....
author = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",25)
with open("informations.txt") as f:
    rd=f.readlines()
author1 = author.render("{}".format(rd[0][0:-1]),True,blue) #Pygame won't wait 
                                                            #so getting IndexError here
age = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",25)
age1 = age.render("{}".format(rd[1]),True,blue)
...
...
...
gameDisplay.blit(author1,(680,15))
gameDisplay.blit(age1,(720,40))
```

This method is almost working, I thought finally I got the solution of this *input* problem in Pygame.But I don't know how to tell Pygame, wait untill I'm done with .exe file, then process your codes.

Comment: You could use `os.system("wtf.exe")` instead.

Comment: you do not need to convert Python script to exe, to run it as a subprocess (`[sys.executable, '/path/to/script']` as a command would work). You do not need to run a Python script as a subprocess in order to execute some Python code without blocking the pygame event loop (you could use `threading`, `multiprocessing`, `concurrent.futures`, `asyncio` modules instead). You should not use `input()` to get user input in a GUI application e.g., see [code near `evt.unicode.isalpha()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14112370/4279) for one possible alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [communicate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) method:

> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate. The optional input argument should be a string to be sent to the child process, or None, if no data should be sent to the child.

So this is the code to do it:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["wtf.exe"])
# block until process done
output, errors = process.communicate()
```

---

### Edit:

As @Padraic suggests, you can use [check_call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call), which is [more informative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106720/python-subprocess-call-check-call-and-returncode-to-find-if-a-command-exist) when failing:

```
try:
    subprocess.check_call([’wtf.exe’])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    pass # handle errors in the called executable
except OSError:
    pass # executable not found
```

---

Another option is [call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute.

So something like this:

```
returncode = subprocess.call(["wtf.exe"])
```

---

And you can also use [wait](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) if you don't care about the data and just want the return code to see if something bad happened. But documentation says you should prefer `communicate`:

> Warning: This will deadlock when using stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use communicate() to avoid that.

Comment: It solved.I actually want to learn how this _communicate()_  works? _output,errors_ ? Can you explain it more please and let me check it as correct answer.

Comment: check_call may be a better option.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham What is the difference between them, could you tell me please?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Why is it favoured over `call`? I use `communicate` most of the time anyway...

Comment: @grrr I added information from the docs for each method, and the names for each function are actual links to the docs.

Comment: if you get a non zero value returned check_call will will raise an error which may be preferable unless you wanted to ignore errors.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham , yeah, just saw that in the docs and in SO, updated answer.

Comment: @ReutSharabani Can I use _subprocess.Popen_ with whole path of file? like _subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Users\pc\Desktop\DENIYORUZFENA\wtf.exe"])_

Comment: @grrr I'm not too familiar with windows, but if you can do it in the terminal, it'll probably work.

Comment: downvote. Don't use `.communicate()` unless you want to pass input/read subprocess' output i.e., remove `Popen().communicate()` (or add something like `stdout=PIPE` to the code), leave `call(cmd)` or `p = Popen(cmd); ...; p.wait()`.