# How to clean terminal(cmd) , after opening another file in terminal

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pygame, subprocess

From [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759254/python-subprocess-popen-with-pygame-how-to-tell-pygame-wait-untill-subproces) question, I solved that problem but now another problem is occured.Now my first .exe file is opening by these codes in Pygame;

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["wtf.exe"])
output, errors = process.communicate()
```

This file (wtf.exe) asking information to user **before** opening the Pygame and putting that information in to the Pygame;

[image]

When I confirm these informations, it's opening the Pygame screen with information I gave in first program and closing the first program;

[image]

So far everything is fine, when I click to the 'play' , it's opening another file in terminal; but last file's datas still there.

[image]

You see, first picture's datas here, it should be without these datas. Why terminal is didn't clean itself? It's another .exe file running in terminal, a new file on a 'new' terminal, but it looks it's not new. How do I clean the terminal after first file processed? As you know these are .exe files working on terminal, and I can't clear the terminal manually, I have to write some codes into that files, but I have no idea what to do.

> **Edit**: I gave some unacceptable informations on purpose and check this picture please:

[image]

> **Edit2**: [**Here**](http://tinypic.com/r/25s8wue/8) is the video of my problem.

Comment: Do you want it to start at the top or can your prompt be at the bottom?

Comment: I want to start it at the top of course, and this problem is really weird. It should be another terminal, because I opening a different .exe file, but as you see first datas still there. The data that I taking from user must NOT be in terminal if second program is running.

Comment: Oh I understand why don't you just use one terminal window and clear it out after the information has been entered just by doing a for loop with empty print statements 2000 will usually clear terminal windows

Comment: @Ondeckshooting Well it's not a solution actually, it's like hiding the first data :-) but I want to clear it, it's more "programmer" also this problem shouldn't be occured, as I said second program is another .exe file..

Comment: I've used this before Its been a long time since I have used this but I think this question is similar to what you are asking and should help you out. I know there's a module that can do all sorts of things with command prompt on windows but nothing on anything Unix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586601/remove-last-stdout-line-in-python

Comment: Your script runs via the console program py.exe, which starts python.exe. When you run `subprocess.Popen('wtf.exe')`, the child process inherits the current console.  You could first run `subprocess.Popen('cls', shell=True)` to have the shell clear the screen. Or you could instruct Windows to create a new console:  `subprocess.Popen('wtf.exe', creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)`.

Answer (score 1):

[`cls` internal command (Windows)](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/99261) / `clear` command on *nix clear the terminal screen and its scrollback buffer if possible:

```
import os

os.system('cls')
```

**Try it** before making a comment.

As an alternative, you could [start a new console window (`creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` on Windows) for each command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19308415/4279) or just the last command instead i.e., when a command ends its window is closed and therefore there is nothing to clean.

You could also run your parent script as a GUI program (use `.pyw` file extension) without the console i.e., if a child process needs the console; it has to allocate its own.

Answer (score 1):

@J.F. Sebastian gave you one approach, which is to clear the screen from within your code.

However, as you are already using pygame, you can use the [`inputbox` module](http://www.pygame.org/pcr/inputbox/) to prompt the user for their input.

This way, you eliminate the problem completely.